# Is there a way to determine the number of PCIe lanes my system has and uses

Tags: linux, windows-10, pci-express

With a core i9-9900K and an ASUS MPG Z390 GAMING PRO CARBON AC/ MPG Z390 GAMING PRO CARBON motherboard, is there a way to determine how many PCIe lanes my system has?

With an ASUS Geforce RTX 2080 installed and allegedly running in x16 mode and an ASUS XG-C100C 10G PCI-E Network Adapter fitted in, is there a way to determine how many lanes are being used?

Lane usage solutions are welcome for both Windows and Fedora.

Comment: In Linux, read `dmidecode` output carefully.  It should list all your PCIe ports along with information about how much lanes, which voltage is supported, is a slot occupied or not, and so on. (And the same about memory slots and so on.)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to provide the basics. Is there a way to check what item is occupying what slot?

Comment: Yes, see "Bus Address" in `dmidecode`? This is the same bus address as in `lspci` output.

Comment: Thank you. Please post your answer as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: A note on Windows: the [GNU for Windows dmidecode port](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/) appears to work and provide the same information in Windows even if it is 11 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information about computer hardware can be found in the DMI table, which is read and parsed with `dmidecode` utility:

```
 # dmidecode
 ...
 Handle 0x0900, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
 System Slot Information
        Designation: PCIe Slot 1
        Type: x16 PCI Express 3
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        ID: 1
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                PME signal is supported
...
```

All slots in this server are empty, so I can't show, but for "In Use" slot there will be a Bus Address entry.

This command also shows which memory this system has, which memory slots are occupied and so on. The `dmidecode` package has other useful utilities, for example, `biosdecode`.

To find out which device has which PCI bus address, we closely look onto `lspci` output from `pci-utils`. This address is in the first column:

```
# dmidecode
...
Handle 0x2902, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
        Reference Designation: Embedded NIC 3
        Type: Ethernet
        Status: Enabled
        Type Instance: 3
        Bus Address: 0000:03:00.0
...

# lspci
...
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
...
```